# Importing using API CSV importer

Tags: import

I am importing a large dataset using  the API CSV importer extension.

The data needs to be divided into 3 chucnks - contact, address and email.

The second two imports I was planning to match up with the first import of contact data by downloading the contacts added inthe first import and adding the civicrm id to the second two imports (and doing the match offline)

However I have come to the third import (email address) and there is no ability to match by contact id.

My plan is to turn it round and import the email first then the contact data and then the address data so I think I have a solution. However, it seems odd to me that I can't upload the email and match against contact ID. The only option seems to be email (match by external identifier).

Am I missing something?

Thanks
Caroline

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the field 'email contact' when importing is actually contact id. So there you go!